# "Thread-first" macro and "thread-last" macro from Clojure implemented on Scheme?

Tags: clojure, scheme, r5rs

I'm trying to implement the macros [`->`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E) and [`->>`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) in Scheme and my final result was:

```
  ;;
  ;; See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E
  ;; for more info.
  ;;
  (define-syntax ->
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ a) a)
      ((_ a (b c ...)) (b a c ...))
      ((_ a b) (b a))      
      ((_ a b c) (-> (-> a b) c))
      ((_ a b ... c) (-> (-> a b ...) c))))

  ;;
  ;; See https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E
  ;; for more info.
  ;;
  (define-syntax ->>
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ a) a)
      ((_ a (b c ...)) (b c ... a))
      ((_ a b) (b a))      
      ((_ a b c) (->> (->> a b) c))
      ((_ a b ... c) (->> (->> a b ...) c))))
```

I have made some tests successfully, but I am not sure if it is 100% correct and if it is 100% optimized.

Is it correct? Is there any way to optimize this? Did I do too much or is it anyway?

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on the question: which Scheme dialect are you using? Because in Racket we already have [threading macros](https://docs.racket-lang.org/threading/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._threading%2Fmain..rkt%29._~7e~3e~3e%29%29), so there's no need to implement them :) . In particular, [~>](https://docs.racket-lang.org/threading/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._threading%2Fmain..rkt%29._~7e~3e%29%29) and [~>>](https://docs.racket-lang.org/threading/index.html#%28form._%28%28lib._threading%2Fmain..rkt%29._~7e~3e~3e%29%29) are supported, among others. Please take a look at the documentation.

Comment: Oscar Lopez, it is R5RS, SISC implementation.